# Running several processes in parallel while reading from Kafka and sending http requests in Python

Tags: python, rest, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, apache-kafka

I have been searching how to open parallel processes in Python and have stumbled upon concurrent futures and multiprocessing as the most interesting options. Sadly I haven't been able to implement them correctly since they seem to be working one worker after another instead of at the same time. Right now my process is taking a little too long and I think I can make it faster.

Say I coded a function in Python that is connecting to a Kafka queue and reading json messages, each message will then be sent to a rest service using requests and getting some information in order to complete the data and be posted afterwards; then I'm just updating my database with the response.
I need to be able to have this function run in several processes and read from the queue at the same time while doing the requests until I'm out messages.

**What would be the best approach to do so?**

Comment: @Fernano Did you make any progress on this?